# funny results with try/catch and sessions

Tags: php, class, session, try-catch

I have these method to handle script notifications inside a class named `KD`.

```
private static $notice=array(); 

public static function SetNotice($type, $text){
    self::$notice[] = array('type'=>$type, 'text'=>$text);
    $_SESSION['notices'] = self::$notice;
}

public static function notice(){
    if($_SESSION['notices']){
        foreach($_SESSION['notices'] as $key=>$note){
            $html .= '<div class="notice-'.$note['type'].'"><p class="icon">'.$note['text'].'</p></div>';
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Adding new notice:

```
KD::SetNotice('type','message');
```

Displaying notices:

```
KD::notice()
```

I also have this method I usually add at the end of all my scripts:

```
public static function redirect($to = http_referer){  //  http_referer is a defined constant to replace $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
    if(!headers_sent()){  return exit(header('Location:'.$to));  } 
    else{  return print_r('<script>window.location = "'.$to.'";</script>');  }
}
```

Example of use:

```
/**
 * Script to be executed
 */
if($action){
    KD::SetNotice('success','All good');
} else {
    KD::SetNotice('error','Something went wrong');
}
KD::redirect();  //  redirects the user back
```

Landing page after execution:

```
<!-- somewhere on that page where I want to show messages  -->
<?=KD::notice()?>
```

This works perfectly. All notices is now returned in the order they are set down to this point.

**My problem:**
But when I add a `try/catch` block into the mix on the landing page, that contains a `KD::SetNotice();`, all notices before is deleted, or overwritten:

```
#   script.php

if($action){
    KD::SetNotice('success','All good');
} else {
    KD::SetNotice('error','Something went wrong');
}
KD::redirect();


#   landing-page.php

echo KD::notice();  //  returns all notices so far

/**
 *   I found that it is neccecary to use try/catch when using DESCRIBE in order to prevent error messages to be displayed when checking if a table exists.
 */
try {
    $describe = $dbh->query('DESCRIBE users');
    $table_exists = true;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    KD::SetNotice('warning','Table does not exists. Please create it in order to continue.');
    $table_exists = false;
}
KD::SetNotice('info','you should know');

KD::notice();  //  only notices set within try/catch is returned, along with notices set after...
```

Somehow when using my `SetNotice`-method inside the `try/catch`, the session that holds the notices is overwritten.
If I remove the `try/catch`, the notices set from both the script and the last one on the landing page is returned..

*Actually. The `try/catch` is interfering with the session that holds the notices. Every notice set before is deleted or overwritten...*

I don't know if this is enought code for you to help me figure out why this is happening, but let me know if there's something I'm not aware of.

Thanks in advance.

*UPDATE*
I just tested to not refreshing the page after the script had been execuded. Meaning I left out the `KD::redirect`-method, and now all notices is displayed.
So the problem happens when I'm redirecting user back...

*UPDATE 2: possible solution*
After I redirected the user at the end of the script, the `$notice`-array was of course reset to empty. Only the notices in the `$_SESSION['notices']` was still available on the landing page.
So when using the `SetNotice()`-method again, I "overwrote" the `SESSION` with new notices.
This resulted in returning only notices set on this page-load, when using `<?=KD::notices()?>` on the landing page..

It makes sense when I thought it through. So I added this at the beginning of my `SetNotice()`-method:

```
#   make sure existing notices is kept after redirection
    if($_SESSION['notices']){
        foreach($_SESSION['notices'] as $key=>$note){  self::$notice[]=array('type'=>$note['type'],'text'=>$note['text']);  }
    }
//
```

Comment: You have not run `session_start()` in this code snippet, is that just because you didnt put it in the snippet or did you actually forget to code it.

Comment: Well.. I have not coded it at all because it seemed to work without it untill I added the `try/catch` block. Where should I add it in my situation?

Comment: I have this added before any of these snippets though: `if(!isset($_SESSION)){  
  session_name('__KD');  
  session_set_cookie_params(0,'/','','',true);  
  session_start();  
 }`

Comment: Before any output it sent to the browser - I cannot reproduce this scenario using [standard static arrays](https://eval.in/415013) or running the code from [this example with sessions](https://eval.in/415016) (locally - eval.in doesn't allow sessions)